# Why is the first step moving with the page when changing the responsive layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

The code in question: https://jsfiddle.net/3uLj8rw6/

Firstly, I'd like to mention that I am still learning HTML, CSS, and Sass.

*"Choose a restaurant"* seems to move with the page itself when adjusting the responsive layout in Chrome.

Is this a problem with the layout of the HTML, the Flex in the CSS, or the Media Query?

`media query` via SASS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:800px) {

    .container--body,
    #restaurants {
        padding: 0px 50px;
    }

    .steps {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        width: 307px;
    }

    body {
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .hero-title__margin {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 172px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

    .container--body {
        gap: 15px;
        margin: 20px 0px 25px 0px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to move with the page itself"? Of course it works as expected. But apparently you expect something else. So what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I think that the problem you are facing is the fact that when using flexbox, any element with a non-defined width will stretch to fill the remaining space on one row. Since Choose a Restaurant has a fixed width and the h1 doesn't, the width of the h1 is stretch to a width that is 100% minus the width of the first step. That's why it seems as if the first step is fixed to the right side, whereas technically it is "pushed" to the right by the h1.

Comment: This has resolved my issue! Thank you!

Going forward, I will remember to always, always, always define a height/width when using Flex.

Comment: don't add the answer within the question. Add it as an answer below